# How to solve the problem with starting devcontainer?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, wsl-2, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I tried to run devcontainer. Set up files:

devcontainer.json

```json
{
    "name": "C++",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1": {}
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/cpp:0-debian-11

ARG REINSTALL_CMAKE_VERSION_FROM_SOURCE="3.22.2"

# Optionally install the cmake for vcpkg
COPY ./reinstall-cmake.sh /tmp/

RUN if [ "${REINSTALL_CMAKE_VERSION_FROM_SOURCE}" != "none" ]; then \
        chmod +x /tmp/reinstall-cmake.sh && /tmp/reinstall-cmake.sh ${REINSTALL_CMAKE_VERSION_FROM_SOURCE}; \
    fi \
    && rm -f /tmp/reinstall-cmake.sh
```

But when i try to run devcontainer i get error:

```
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.771Z] ERROR: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.863Z] Stop (969 ms): Run: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f C:\Users\BOGUS_~1.NEW\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.25.2-1671821861765\Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-test-9da7bcb89243449acfae569e26bf0e4b --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-context dev_containers_feature_content_source=C:\Users\BOGUS_~1.NEW\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.25.2-1671821861765 --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_IMAGE_USER=root --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_FEATURE_CONTENT_SOURCE=dev_container_feature_content_temp c:\Projects\docker_projects\Cpp\test\.devcontainer
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.865Z] Error: Command failed: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f C:\Users\BOGUS_~1.NEW\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.25.2-1671821861765\Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-test-9da7bcb89243449acfae569e26bf0e4b --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-context dev_containers_feature_content_source=C:\Users\BOGUS_~1.NEW\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.25.2-1671821861765 --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_IMAGE_USER=root --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_FEATURE_CONTENT_SOURCE=dev_container_feature_content_temp c:\Projects\docker_projects\Cpp\test\.devcontainer
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.866Z]     at Doe (c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1894:1669)
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.866Z]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.866Z]     at async EF (c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1893:1978)
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.866Z]     at async uT (c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1893:901)
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.866Z]     at async Poe (c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1899:2128)
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.867Z]     at async Zf (c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1899:3278)
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.867Z]     at async aue (c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2020:15276)
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.867Z]     at async oue (c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2020:15030)
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.882Z] Stop (5862 ms): Run: C:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --workspace-folder c:\Projects\docker_projects\Cpp\test --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Projects\docker_projects\Cpp\test --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Projects\docker_projects\Cpp\test\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.882Z] Exit code 1
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.889Z] Command failed: C:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\Bogus_Kladik.NEW-PC\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --workspace-folder c:\Projects\docker_projects\Cpp\test --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Projects\docker_projects\Cpp\test --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Projects\docker_projects\Cpp\test\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-12-23T18:57:44.889Z] Exit code 1
```

How can I fix this problem?

Of the attempts, I can note the update of Docker Desktop, the update of wsl

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be related to the use of BuildKit and Inline Cache in Docker.

The work-around suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7958) is either:

- To disable BuildKit in Docker:

  - Under Linux:

    ```
    # in /etc/bash.bashrc
    export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
    ```
  - Under Docker Dashboard:

    Go to Settings > Docker Engine and set 'buildkit' to 'false':

    ```
    "features": {
      "buildkit": false
    },
    ```
- To disable the Inline Cache, either:

  - in the Dockerfile :

    ```
    "args": {
      "BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE": "0"
    }
    ```
  - in the devcontainer.json:

    ```
    "build": {
      "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
      "args": {
        "BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE": "0"
      }
    },
    ```
  - in the docker-compose.yml:

    ```
     services:
       app:
         build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: Dockerfile
           args:
             BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE: 0
    ```